# Android LikeView error

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using facebook android sdk v3.19.1 in my android app. I try to use [LikeView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button), but it's only working with users who added to the facebook app settings in the roles section as developer or tester. If I try to click the like button with a normal facebook user or a test user it's appears and disappears quickly and gives back the following error message:
error_description: The like dialog is only available to developers and testers.
error: server_error
error_reason: dialog_disabled

My app is pubilc and I turned on the Single Sign On and Deep Linking options.
I'm using facebook LoginButton and ask for "publish_actions" permission before the user click's the like button, but it's still gives me the error message.

My problem is that I can't make the like button working with test users. I submitted the like button for review to the facebook, but they gives me the following response: Please confirm your app is working correctly and that you can publish likes with a test user.
Please somebody help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I also having the same problem. When I use a real user it does work.

Comment: Does it work for you with a real user who is not listed in the facebook settings roles section?

Comment: No, it will only work on users in the roles section. The interesting part is that the Facebook team asked me to test the like button with a test user.

Comment: I am also facing this issue If some one solved this please post solution here

Comment: I am seeing this same problem on iOS and Android.  Getting the same error in the URL in the openURL method in iOS and getting a Canceled state in Android OnActivityResult code.  Tried a new Facebook account and that does not work.  Both accounts are non-testing accounts.  Any help from the Facebook side on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found this on the Facebook docs.

> Test users cannot become a fan of a public Facebook Page or create
>   content on them, such as writing on a Page's wall. A Test user can
>   however view and interact with any app tab on the Page associated with
>   the app that created them.

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users?locale=es_ES)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the FB test user account for your app? Test accounts are not allowed to Like a page. I had the same problem. I changed to using my actual FB account and the LikeButton worked perfectly fine!

Comment: Yes, I use test user, but I tried to like facebook graph objects, not facebook pages.