# iOS Facebook Like Button Not Working With iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

Trying to add the Facebook Like Button to an iOS App.  Followed the directions online and am seeing an issue.

Without the Facebook App Installed on Simulator (8.x, 7,x):

When pressing the F Like button, we see a transition to Facebook.com but then quickly returns to the iOS App.  It does not go to the proper Facebook Like page where the user can like the URL passed.

In the iOS app, the openURL method is being called and the Facebook

```
wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL: url sourceApplication: sourceApplication];
```

is being called and it returns YES.

Please note that we are also using the Facebook Login Button that is working fine in this app.

The user has already been authenticated with the Facebook Login Button at this point.

Any hints on this would be appreciated.

We are using Facebook iOS SDK 3.21.1

[Addition]

See this article

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529314/android-likeview-error
```

This is what we are seeing in the the URL Error Message in openURL

```
The like dialog is only available to developers and testers
```

Which kinda does not make sense?  Regular users should be able to see the like dialog to like the item?

Comment: You need to submit your usage of the native like button for approval before it can be used publicly. Go to the Status & Review section of your app settings, click on Start a Submission, scroll to the bottom (in the Features section) and click on Native Like Button.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, will do and it looks like we have to submit a version the iOS and Android app either from the store or a sample build.

Comment: For comment on the the above, if the Facebook Account is the Developer Account for the App or a designated Facebook Tester Account setup by the Facebook Developer Page, it will work at least for testing.

Comment: Once the app was "approved" by Facebook, none testing accounts work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Facebook Like Buttons on iOS and Android.

After you have integrated the latest SDK and you want to test....

1) You must use a Facebook Account that is either the Developer account for the app (the account that the Facebook ID for the app was created) OR a linked tester Facebook account to the Facebook Developer account.

2) You have to use this account to login with on for the App.

3) When testing a "BETA" banner will be on the target page.

4) If these are not in place, for iOS at least you will get an error message in the URL in the openURL routine in the AppDelegate.  For Android you will get a "CANCEL" status in your onActivityResult routine.

```
The like dialog is only available to developers and testers
```

Hope this helps.

To fully enable the like button for production, please see Ming Li comments above.

Comment: Thanks for that! I have added test user and now I see "BETA" banner. However, I get this error that there is server error (all the time), so I don't have "only available for testers" error. Maybe You know what to do with this?

Comment: i have the developer account and not work fore me.Once tab the like button it take me to empty page on safari with done button. when click the done button it return to the app. any help?

Comment: facing blank screen issue when tap on fb like button in iOS, it was working earlier but since last few days it stopped working.