# Android Facebook Like Button Without Facebook App Installed Not Working

Tags: android, facebook-like

Have implemented the Facebook Like Button on Android along with Facebook Login

When the Facebook App is installed all works fine.  Even if not logged in with Facebook, if user selects the Facebook Like button, it logs in and allows the like / unlike, etc.

If the Facebook App is NOT installed, when the like button is selected when not logged into Facebook, the Username / Password is displayed and with a correct Username / Password entered, a blank screen is displayed with a cancel at the bottom for a bit and then goes away.  Can not change the like status, etc.

Also, the username and password are not saved from session to session like when the Facebook App is installed.

The Facebook like button is defined like

```
        <com.facebook.widget.LikeView
                android:id="@+id/button_facebook_like_about"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

Code looks like

```
import com.facebook.widget.LikeView;
…
LikeView faceBookLikeView = (LikeView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_like_about);
faceBookLikeView.setObjectId(GlobalConstants.FacebookLikeAppPage);
faceBookLikeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BOX_COUNT);
faceBookLikeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
```

Comment: Nope, Facebook as been silent on this so far.  We are deciding not to show the Facebook Like Button if Facebook App is NOT installed.

Comment: But does it work if the facebook app is installed? I have it installed and still the same -or it will start working after facebook approval process?

Comment: Yes, works if it is installed.  Please see this posting if you are using an app page.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324881/ios-facebook-like-button-not-working-with-ios-app  this is with iOS, but I was getting a Canceled error response on Android when this was the case, trying to use and app page link when it was not approved.